# What IC is marked WDG273?

Tags: usb, uart, watchdog, pc

I want to buy this USB watchdog V5.0 in order to restart my computer in case the PC hangs. As I'm an electronic designer, I was checking the hardware and when I saw the main IC reference, I said: "I don't know this IC, let's look on internet." The  result of the search was interesting: I didn't find anything about the WDG273.

See picture from Amazon:

[image]

It should be a USB <-> UART TTL converter but it's impossible for me to find the datasheet on the internet.

I'm thinking that these guys, before they uploaded the picture to Amazon, edited the picture in order to 'hide' the IC reference and invented a new one.

What IC is this?

Comment: If I had to guess... WDG is watchdog 273... Interestingly it has a USB interface... I don't think it is just a converter since I see no other processor on here...

Comment: I look in the internet and cannot find any reference. The first letters (WDG) of the ic probably not refer to the ic brand, I think it's an abbreviation of WatchDog. If you are an engineer and you are agree with me, I will never buy a hardware like this when its no description of the hardware. You have 2 options, look for another better or make yourself a new one.

Comment: Definitely build your own; there must be a dozen ways to tell if a PC has frozen. WDG could be a custom chip, or like you say, a disguised or re-marked one.  Try rubbing the lettering with Lacquer thinner or acetone.

Comment: It is not worth the effort to make your own. Google search for "USB watchdog" produces 5,420,000 hits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The part looks like the original markings are sanded down and replaced with custom markings. It will be next to impossible to know which chip it really is.

However there are multiple clones and versions of those kind of products, and the V5 version was made with STM32F042F6 MCU.

So it can be any USB capable microcontroller running firmware that makes it present itself as a generic CDC class USB serial port and when it looks like PC has crashed then after some time it will push reset button for you.